# How can i order by Current Date in Linq/Sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq

I am fetching data from a table but i want to Sort data using a column "ScheduledDate" with Current Date on top(If not current date then nearest date on top) and rest after that even if there is a future date with it.

Data

```
ScheduledDate

2019-08-28 18:30:00.000
2019-08-27 18:30:00.000
2019-08-27 11:49:57.087
2019-08-27 12:08:56.827
2019-08-20 06:42:16.603
2019-08-20 06:47:33.970
2019-08-20 11:15:36.780 
2019-08-20 11:18:20.853
2019-08-20 11:18:56.120
2019-08-20 11:20:16.520
2019-08-20 11:21:09.600
2019-08-21 18:30:00.000
2019-08-21 18:30:00.000
2019-08-21 18:30:00.000
2019-08-22 18:30:00.000
2019-08-22 18:30:00.000
2019-08-22 18:30:00.000
2019-08-26 18:30:00.000
```

Desired Result:

```
ScheduledDate

2019-08-27 11:49:57.087
2019-08-27 12:08:56.827    
2019-08-27 18:30:00.000    
2019-08-20 06:42:16.603
2019-08-20 06:47:33.970
2019-08-20 11:15:36.780 
2019-08-20 11:18:20.853
2019-08-20 11:18:56.120
2019-08-20 11:20:16.520
2019-08-20 11:21:09.600
2019-08-21 18:30:00.000
2019-08-21 18:30:00.000
2019-08-21 18:30:00.000
2019-08-22 18:30:00.000
2019-08-22 18:30:00.000
2019-08-22 18:30:00.000
2019-08-26 18:30:00.000
2019-08-28 18:30:00.000
```

Comment: [orderbydescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: Where is your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional key in your `order by`:

```
order by (case when convert(date, scheduleddate) = convert(date, getdate()) then 1 else 2 end),
         scheduleddate asc
```

Comment: Hey Thanks This works, Do you know how can i do it usign Linq?

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your table is Orders

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var result = context.Orders
              .OrderByDecending(o => o.ScheduledDate.Date == today)
              .ThenBy(o => o.ScheduledDate)
              .Select(o => o)
              .ToList()
```

This will sort the current date first and rest of the dates in ascending order. Since you want to get nearest date on top when today is not available, You might have to first get the nearest date with a different query and replace `today` with `nearestDate` in the above query.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most straightforward way would be to use a UNION operator. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ScheduledDate = GETDATE() ORDER BY ScheduledDate DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ScheduledDate DESC
```

It's not wonderfully performant because it requires two separate select statements, but it's easy to read and maintain.

edit: No idea how to do this in LINQ, but this works for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help from @GordonLinoff 's SQL query, i have created the Linq query:

For Linq:

```
DbContext.Table.
OrderBy(x=> (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(x.ScheduledDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")), DateTime.Parse(today)) == 0 ? 1 : 2 )).ThenByDescending(x=>x.ScheduledDate);
```

For SQL :

```
order by (case when convert(date, scheduleddate) = convert(date, getdate()) then 1 else 2 end),
scheduleddate asc
```